# Pip installing a package inside of a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I have installed Apache Superset from its Helm Chart in a Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster. I need to `pip install` a package that is not installed when installing the Helm Chart. If I connect to the Kubernetes bash shell like this:

`kubectl exec -it superset-4934njn23-nsnjd /bin/bash`

Inside there's no python available, no pip and apt-get doesn't find most of the packages.

I understand that during the container installation process the packages are listed in the Dockerfile, I suppose that I need to fork the docker container, modify the Dockerfile, register the container to a container registry and make a new Helm Chart that will run this container.

But all this seems too complicated for a simple `pip install`, is there a simpler way to do this?

Links:

Docker- https://hub.docker.com/r/amancevice/superset/

Helm Chart - https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/superset

Comment: Docker has an excellent tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  The mechanics of it are quite simple (especially for a simple `pip install`); the hard part is getting your image pushed to somewhere the k8s cluster can find it.  You'll have to set up some sort of registry to run your application, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Murli mentioned, you should use `pip3`. However, one thing you should remember is, `helm` is for managing k8s, i.e. what goes into the cluster should be traceable. So I recommend you the following:

```
$ helm get stable/superset
```

modify the values.yaml. In my case, I added jenkins-job-builder to pip3:

```
initFile: |-
  pip3 install jenkins-job-builder
  /usr/local/bin/superset-init --username admin --firstname admin --lastname user --email admin@fab.org --password admin
  superset runserver
```

and just pass the `values.yaml` to `helm install`.

```
$ helm install --values=values.yaml stable/superset
```

Thats it.

```
 $ kubectl exec -it doltish-gopher-superset-696448b777-8b9c6 which jenkins-jobs
 /usr/local/bin/jenkins-jobs
 $
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker file seems to be installing python3 package. 
Try 'python3' or "pip3" instead of 'python'/'pip'

Comment: Indeed, I also got this answer at the Kubernetes slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

Make the container, a little more dev work and many fewer alerts from pager duty

Comment: yes, this is a long term solution, but I wanted to quickly install the needed package so that I can test the build.